# Cordova Bluetooth LE connection time

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, bluetooth-lowenergy

How long does it generally take to connect to a BLE device using cordova / phonegap application?
 
I'm currently using cordova-ble-central and struggling with the connection time. 
iOS connects better, takes around 5 seconds or so. 
But Android takes a ways longer, around 8 or more seconds. Sometimes it takes 40 seconds. 
I've tried many different things but couldn't resolve this. 
So my question is, 'Is it possible to make connection time lower than 3 seconds with cordova app?'

Comment: What advertising interval do you have on the peripheral?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's 1800ms.

Comment: Since standard Android parameters are: scan for 30 ms, then idle 1250 ms and repeat, it's about 2.3% probability that each advertisement packet will be received. Try to decrease the advertisement interval in your peripheral to make it connect faster. The other option is to use "direct connect" rather than "auto connect" in Android's bluetooth API (not sure how it works in cordova). That way you can connect to one device with a timeout of 30 seconds or so, but with a much higher scan window per scan interval.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. As tested, reducing advertisement interval gives much better connection. However because it takes too much battery, I decided to fix this issue with codes.